# sass/scss import from variable not possible

Tags: sass

Hi all I would like to create a variable used to import file like this in SCSS:

```
$theme : 'my_theme';
@import "#{$theme}/import";
```

but this return me this error:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: #{$theme}/import.
```

I haven't found information about that only that is not possible.
Does exist a workaround to make it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original implementation only worked when the interpolated string or url() was a valid string/url; this means that you couldn't include e.g. quotes or closing parentheses within the string/url (e.g. `@import "#{"foo.css"}"`)

More information you can find here: 
https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/49